# Square inscribed in large triangle, given areas of small triangles

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

> Shown in the figure below, $DEFG$ is a square inscribed in $\triangle ABC$.
>
> Given that the areas of $\triangle ADG, \triangle BED, \triangle CGF$ is $3, 5$ and $7$ respectively.
>
> Find the area of square $DEFG$.
>
> [image: Figure]

What I noticed is that
$$\triangle ADG \sim\triangle BED\sim\triangle CGF$$

Given the respective areas, we can find the ratio of their side lengths.

How can I move on from there?

Comment: The similarity you have mentioned is not correct. Just use the fact that $\triangle ADG \sim \triangle ABC$ and assume their sides are in ratio $x:1$. Give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the side of the square be $s$ and let altitude from $A$ to $DG$ be $x$
$$BE = \frac{10}{s}, \ FC = \frac{14}{s}, \ x = \frac{6}{s}$$
Sum of Areas = Total Area
$$7+5+3+s^2 = \frac12 \bigg(\frac{14}{s}+\frac{10}{s}+s\bigg)\bigg(\frac{6}{s}+s\bigg)$$
$$\text{Area of Square} = s^2 = 12$$

Answer (score 1):

Setup equations.

(1)...... $(a + b)x/2 = (5 + 7)$; where a = BE and b = FC

(2)...... $[(3 + 5 + 7 + x^2)/3] = [((a + b) + x)/x]^2$

Eliminating $(a + b)$ to get an equation in $x$.